# Controller Unit test with MockMvc

Tags: testing, junit, mockito, mockmvc

Fairly new to Java, as well as Mockito and MockMvc and unit tests in general. I am also new with springboot. My basic understanding is that for unit tests I only need to test the methods in the given file that is under testing.

File needed to be tested:

```java
@RestController 
@RequestMapping(value = "some string") 
public class Controller{
@AutoWired 
private Service service;

@GetMapping(path= "some string")
public List<ObjectClass> getAllDomainData(){
return service.getAllDetails();
}
}
```

My test class

```java
@WebMvcTest(Controller.class)
public class ControllerTest{
@MockBean
private Service service;
@AutoWired
private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
@AutoWired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Test
public void shouldCreateMockMvc(){ assertNotNull(mockMvc);}

@Test
public void getAllDetails() throws Exception {
when(service.getAllDetails())
    .thenReturn(List.of(new ObjectClass()));
}
```

This compiles and runs.... but is it testing what I need it to test to do a efficient Unit test on the file? Im just trying to learn, go easy on me please.

Comment: Your test only checks that web slice of web context can be created. In particular, `getAllDetails` test tests nothing. First find a good tutorial, the ones at Baeldung are  pretty comprehensive: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing#unit-testing-with-webmvctest